# CSS: even text and image level? (box-sizing)

Tags: css

How do I make the text so the image even out?

For example "gone in 60 seconds" should not push the image upward, but instead push the text downwards.

[image]

Comment: please share your code see here : [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: try vertical-align:top in <li>

Comment: OW it was that simple. Thankyou very much aashi! :-)